# import from raima

Tags: import, raima

I have an old in DOS program (1) with Raima(db_vista) database and i must
create import data from program (1) to other program (2).
Program (1) has *.dat and *.key files, but i can't find *.dbd file. Is it
possible that file *.dbd not exists? Can it be compiled in EXE?
Is it possible export data to .txt files from .key and .dat files when dbd
file not exists?
My program (2) must import this data...

Best regards
(sorry for my poor english)

Omega

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDM_Embedded supposedly has something to with Raima. Please tell us more about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

We use RAIMA extensively at work.  Any RAIMA version before ~4.5 should have a DBD file (all newer ones might as well).  If your program executes, it must be accessing the DBD file somehow.  Do you have the source code available?

Comment: Maybe you can help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264419/dump-all-raima-db-vista-version-3-20-data-to-text